# Proper implementation of the Repository pattern in NestJS

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs, repository-pattern

Analyzing the NestJS documentation and their sample source codes, it is difficult to find a solution in which there would be a Respository pattern between the service layer and the database layer (e.g. MongoDB).

Rather, NestJS performs database operations directly in the Service class, e.g. in the CatsService class.

This leads to several problems:

1. It is difficult to change the type of database because its usage is in different services
2. The model (Document Mongo) is used in database schemas, in the service class, in the controller, and if GraphQL is used, also in Resolvers, which results in the use of Mongo types in different layers and causes various problems with TypeScript
3. Mixing the business logic in the service class (e.g. CatsService) with the database handling logic
4. Others ...

CatsService example from NestJS documentation:

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cat } from './interfaces/cat.interface';
import { CreateCatDto } from './dto/create-cat.dto';

@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('CAT_MODEL')
    private catModel: Model<Cat>,
  ) {}

  async create(createCatDto: CreateCatDto): Promise<Cat> {
    const createdCat = new this.catModel(createCatDto);
    return createdCat.save();
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<Cat[]> {
    return this.catModel.find().exec();
  }
}
```

First problem is when we import the Model from mongoose in the CatsService:

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
```

Next problem is when the Model/Document is returned to the client's layer (to the controller or resolver):

```
private catModel: Model<Cat>,
...
  async findAll(): Promise<Cat[]> {
    return this.catModel.find().exec();
  }
```

As a consequence of the previous problems, the controller or resolver starts using MongoDB Models creating a high coupling between the controller or resolver and the database and its types:

```
import { ParseIntPipe, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Args, Mutation, Query, Resolver, Subscription } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions';
import { Cat } from '../graphql.schema';
import { CatsGuard } from './cats.guard';
import { CatsService } from './cats.service';
import { CreateCatDto } from './dto/create-cat.dto';

const pubSub = new PubSub();

@Resolver('Cat')
export class CatsResolver {
  constructor(private readonly catsService: CatsService) {}

  @Query('cats')
  @UseGuards(CatsGuard)
  async getCats() {
    return this.catsService.findAll();
  }
```

Problem starts here:

```
import { Cat } from '../graphql.schema';
```

An additional problem arises when instead of GQL we use REST with TypeScript:

```
import { Customer } from './models/customer.model';
import { CustomerService } from './customer.service';

@Controller('customer')
export class CustomerController {
  constructor(
    private customerService: CustomerService,
  ) {}

  @Get(':id')
  async getCustomer(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<Customer> {
    const customer = await this.customerService.findById(id) as Customer;
    return customer;
  }

}
```

In the line below we have an error:

> Conversion of type
> 'import("c:/Test/src/customer/customer.schema").Customer' to type
> 'import("c:/Test/src/customer/models/customer.model"). Customer' may
> be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the
> other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown'
> first.

```
const customer = await this.customerService.findById(id) as Customer;
```

This is because in the controller we declare returning the Business Model and the customerService class returns the MongoDB object

```
import { Customer } from './models/customer.model';
```

**Repository Pattern?**

To solve the problems described earlier we can use the popular Repository Pattern - right?
So, I have found an article like this, which explains some implementation of the repository pattern in the NestJS and with MongoDB:
[Implementing a Generic Repository Pattern Using NestJS](https://betterprogramming.pub/implementing-a-generic-repository-pattern-using-nestjs-fb4db1b61cce)

Unfortunately, in my opinion, such an implementation of the Repository pattern may not be applicable in real cases and may be limited by the consequences that I described in the comment to this article:

> Thanks for the article, I'm wondering what if the model contains a
> nested object and we want to update the nested object by its ID? For
> instance we have a customer with many addressess as a nested array of
> Address object. Accoring to the REST apoproach we shoud be able to
> update the adresss by id like PUT /customer/{ID}/address/ID - how can
> we achive this wit the generic repository? In my opinion the generic
> repository assumes that we have simple database uperations but it is
> quite rare requirement and the life is not so simple, so in the
> business apllications we would have to update more complex objects and
> support updating nested objects as well. The same problem aplies to
> the insert and delete operations as well. What do you thing about
> this?

So the described implementation of the Repository pattern does not seem to meet the requirements of a real system.

Do you share my concerns contained in my above comment to the article and if so, how to solve the above problems to achieve:

1. Apply the Repository pattern (especially in MongoDB) **properly**
2. Separate the controller/resolver layer from the service layer and the database layer
3. Be able to perform operations on nested documents by their ID, e.g. updating, deleting, inserting

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation:

Base repository:

```
export class Repository<T> {
  repository: Model<T>;

  constructor(
    repository: Model<T, Record<string, never>, Record<string, never>>,
  ) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  async find(filter: FilterQuery<T | any>, projection?: any): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.repository.find(filter, projection);
  }

  async findById(
    id: string,
    projection?: ProjectionType<T>,
    options?: QueryOptions<T>,
  ): Promise<T> {
    return this.repository.findById(id, projection, options);
  }

  async findOne(
    filter?: FilterQuery<T>,
    projection?: ProjectionType<T>,
    options?: QueryOptions<T>,
  ): Promise<T> {
    return this.repository.findOne(filter, projection, options);
  }

  async create(doc: T | AnyObject | DocumentDefinition<T>): Promise<T> {
    return this.repository.create(doc);
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Entity repository:

```
export default class UserRepository extends Repository<UserDocument> {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {
    super(userModel);
  }

  async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<UserDocument> {
    return this.findOne({ email });
  }
}
```

Service:

```
export default class UserService {
  constructor(private readonly userRepository: UserRepository) {}

  async createUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<UserDocument> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findByEmail(email);

    if (user) {
      throw new UserAlreadyExistsException();
    }

    const createdUser = await this.userRepository.create({ email, password });

    return createdUser;
  }
}
```

User module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [UserRepository, UserService],
  exports: [UserRepository, UserService],
})
export default class UserModule {}
```

Mongo schema:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';

export type UserDocument = HydratedDocument<User>;

@Schema({
  versionKey: false,
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: (doc, ret) => {
      delete ret._id;
    },
  },
})
export class User {
  @Prop({
    type: String,
    required: true,
  })
  email: string;

  @Prop({
    type: String,
    required: true,
  })
  password: string;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

Comment: Isn't there high coupling with mongo going on here? export class Repository<T> {
  repository: Model<T>;

Comment: Also here is high coupling in my opinion: async createUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<UserDocument>